# Laravel 5, have full url as a route parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to pass a full url as a route parameter on my laravel 5 application, the thing is as follows. I'm creating a thumbnail service that having the url of the original photo resizes it and streams it back to the browser.
For example, I need the img source to have an src like this:

```
<img src="http://host.com/generate-thumb/300x300/http://host.com/images/media1.png"/>
```

So in the controller I can get the original image url like this:

```
public function thumbAction(Request $request, $size, $original_url){

   dd($size, $original_url);

}
```

And my route definition as follows:

```
Route::get('/generate-thumb/{size}/{original_url}', array(
   'as' => 'thumb_hook',
   'uses' => 'ThumbController@thumbAction'
));
```

I have done it that way but the server responds with a 404 error.

I have also specified an url pattern in the `where` method of the route definition.

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: Is the `src` attribute for the `img` in your example done on purpose?

Comment: you have a slash between `size` and `original_url`, did you try adding a slash between `300` and `http`?

Comment: Well, first of all you cannot have two semicolons in a URL. That image will never work.

Comment: @Sturm - he's accepting these variables as GET parameters. It will work.

Comment: @microtony yes, my mistake, I will edit the question.

Comment: @Sturm the url is valid, look at thus url used by thumbor to generate thumbnails. http://162.248.55.45:8888/unsafe/300x300/https://www.entrenamiento.com/es/images/large.png

Comment: You really shouldn’t be passing full URLs as a parameter like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue that you're running into is that the url parameters are, by default, delimited by forward slashes (`/`). Since one of your parameters will contain forward slashes, you run into a special situation.

Given your current route definition, and given the url `http://host.com/generate-thumb/300x300/http://host.com/images/media1.png`, what happens is that your `size` parameter gets `300x300`, your `original_url` parameter gets `http:`, and then there are a bunch more parameters. Since you don't have a route defined like this, you get a 404.

In order to allow a parameter to accept forward slashes, you will need to define a regex constraint for that parameter. You need to define your route like this:

```
Route::get('/generate-thumb/{size}/{original_url}', array(
        'as' => 'thumb_hook',
        'uses' => 'ThumbController@thumbAction'
    ))
    ->where('original_url', '.*');
```

This `.*` constraint will allow this parameter to accept any character, including forward slashes. Note that when you do this, this parameter will need to be the last defined parameter, since it eats all the forward slashes and you won't be able to delimit any other route parameters.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my day. I tried another regular expression but with no luck but yours works as expected. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the original URL like this...

```
<img src="http://host.com/generate-thumb/300x300?image=http%3A%2F%2Fhost.com%2Fimages%2Fmedia1.png"/>
```

Note that I've used urlencode on the path to make it URL safe.

Then in your controller, you can simply use `$original= Input::get('image');`

Comment: I don't know if you'll be revisiting this question, so I just wanted to ping you to let you know you can do this, as I've shown in my answer. Personally, I probably would go the way of GET parameters as well, but this /can/ be done with route parameters if one wishes.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the misinformation from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate :

```
<img src="http://host.com/generate-thumb/300x300/http://host.com/images/media1.png"/>
```

Use the `route()` helper, then pass an array for the parameters.

Route.php

```
 Route::get('/generate-thumb/{size}/{original_url}', array(
       'as' => 'thumb_hook',
       'uses' => 'ThumbController@thumbAction'
    ));
```

on your blade file :

```
<img src="{{ route('thumb_hook',[ 
    'size' => '300x300' ,
    'original_url' => 'http://host.com/images/media1.png'
 ]) }}"/>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-route

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do something like this:

```
<?php $url = sprintf('http://example.com/%s?image=%s', $size, url_encode($original_url); ?> 
<img src='{{ $url }}'>
```

`url_encode()` will make that URL safe to pass as a GET parameter.

Edit for comment:

This doesn't work because of the way Laravel is parsing the URL and it's parameters. It sees `300x300/http://` and finds an empty parameter. If you can remove the http:// and still have your functionality then it will work just fine. `urlencode` is not going to fix this problem.

Comment: That's the easy way, there has to be a way to pass a full url to the route.

Comment: @asolenzal I've updated my question to explain why your way is not working.

Comment: I will test your way. Thanks

Comment: @asolenzal I am sorry again about leaving out some information, any instance of / in your URL is going to break it in the same way. Only removing http:// is not enough. You could get around this by replacing each slash with a character that will not occur in the URL elsewhere, then undo later. I"m not sure what your constraints are.